# Can we encourage users to use OS specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've had to ask many times what flavour of Linux is being used in the question. I know there are only three, but answers can vary wildly depending on which is being used.

For example:

- [What's the quickest way to start playing a movie after attaching power?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/146/whats-the-quickest-way-to-start-playing-a-movie-after-attaching-power)
- [What is the simplest way to setup and run XBMC?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32/setting-up-xbmc)
- [IPv6 connectivity](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37/ipv6-connectivity)

I know that sometimes a all encompassing answer is best, but often it makes the answer fractured and overly large.

Does anyone agree and is there anything we can do to encourage the use of OS tags for these kinds of questions? A bullet in the FAQ perhaps?

Comment: A good idea methinks. It strikes me that the most logical place to "encourage" an OS-id tag would be in the same code that checks if a tag has been entered at all; i.e. instead of "*Please enter at least one tag; see a list of popular tags.*", use "*Please enter at least two tags; one to identify the OS, the other(s) to identify the subject area(s); see a list of popular tags.*"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you Jivings. Like you said, answers could be different depending on the OS version they are running.  Not sure how to encourage people to use them though.  The FAQ page might be good idea.